# Javascript: Проверка существования объекта n-ой вложенности

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть объект с произвольным уровнем вложенности.

```
obj = {"test":
        {
           "test1":{"key1":"val1"},
           "test2":{"key2":"val2"}
         }
    };
```

Как мне проверить существование какого либо "ключа"?

Например, в PHP если бы `obj` был бы массивом, я бы написал:

```
if($obj['test']['test1']['key1']){
     echo 'ok';
}
```

Причем, не важно, какой бы не верный был ключ во всей цепочке ассоциативного массива, ошибки бы не было. К примеру, `$obj['test4']['test10']['key4']`, тогда условие бы не выполнилось.

**В Javascript я столкнулся с проблемой, что подобным образом проверить не получается**:

```
if(obj['test']['test2']['key1']){
    console.log('есть');
}
//Ошибка :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key1' of undefined
```

Я нашел способ проверить определенный ключ, например,

```
console.log(obj['test']['test1'].hasOwnProperty('key2')); //даст true

console.log(obj['test']['test1'].hasOwnProperty('key3')); //даст false
```

Или на уровень выше:

```
console.log(obj['test'].hasOwnProperty('test1'));//даст true
```

Но не хотелось бы каждый раз проверять каждый ключ, тем более, что каких-то ключей может попросту не быть, если объект будет с одним уровнем вложенности.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему проверки всей цепочки объекта?** Если есть ключ, то true, если нет - false?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы видимо заработались\глаз замылился. Посмотрите на своё объявление объекта, а потом на объявление и проверку в ответе ниже

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd Вы абсолютно правы, поправил!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [реализация](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.10/lodash.js#L3048) `_get` от `lodash`, можете ее использовать ( ниже упрощенный вариант )

```
function baseGet(object, path) {
  path = path.split('.');

  var index = 0,
      length = path.length;

  while (object != null && index < length) {
    object = object[path[index++]];
  }
  return (index && index == length) ? object : undefined;
}

const obj = {
    "test": {
       "test1":{"key1":"val1"},
       "test2":{"key2":"val2"}
     }
};

console.log(baseGet(obj, 'test.test4.key2'))
```

Вернет либо значения св-во, либо `undefined`. Проверять вот так

```
if(baseGet(object, 'prop.prop1') !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вас ничего не смущает здесь? => 
`{"test":
         {"test1":{"key1":"val1"},
          {"key2":"val2"},
        }
}`

Может быть Вы хотели сделать так?

```js
let obj={"test":
         {
           "test1":{"key1":"val1"},
           "test2":{"key2":"val2"}
         }
        };
if(obj.test.test2.key2){
    console.log('есть');
}
```

Comment: Да так работает. Но если вы вместо `test2` напишите `test3` в условии if, то будет ошибка.

Comment: Qwerty_Wasd Например, при использовании Ajax, каждый раз от сервера приходит разный состав данных. В этом случае, хотелось подстраховаться, на наличие 'есть' или 'нет' конкретных данных.

Comment: Даже написав свой метод, который будет проходить по всему объекту в поисках нужного свойства, Вы в параметре будете указывать конкретно его имя. Что и подтверждает своим примером **ThisMan**

Comment: Поэтому простое условие, предпочтительнее, чем подключать lodash или другие лишние телодвижения. Реализация метода была бы уместна, если например Вы бы проверяли  свойство на наличие по значению. Если литерал принадлежит одному из них, значит.....какое-то действие. Но это лично мои мысли. Конечно релевантность примера зависит от предлагаемых обстоятельств